# codeigniter: rating count with percentage

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table rating like this

```
    id      user      rating
    1       A           1
    2       B           2
    3       A           5
    4       A           3
```

I want to take rating 1 =20,2=40,3=60,4=80,5=100

How to get value of A

I need to show like this

```
      20+100+60/3= 60%(3 rating)
```

How to write query with model,view,controller in codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it like this:

Note: Its just the **LOGIC**

```
select (sum(rating)*20/ count(rating)) as rating, user
from table_name
group by user
```

Comment: can you write this query in codeigniter way and i want count also

Comment: Sorry not a codeigniter guy. But let me see if I can come up.

Comment: See this link to  convert

Comment: How are you going to know which user got which rating?

Comment: just add another column in select query. @Strawberry I think its easily understandable.